# How to draw vertical brace right side of a vertical line with node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, braces

I want to  draw  the following figure (with a node which is not shown).

[image]

I obtained this with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
$\left.\begin{array}{rr}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,1)--(0,0);
\draw (-.1,1)--(.1,1);
\draw (-.1,-.0181)--(.1,-.0181);
\draw (-.1,1/2)--(.1,1/2);
%\node[left] at (0,1) {1};
%\node[left] at (0,1/2) {1/2};
%\node[left] at (0,0) {2/3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{array}\right\}MM$

\vspace{-1.3ex}

$\left.\begin{array}{rr}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,3)--(0,0);
\draw (-.1,3.01)--(.1,3.01);
\draw (-.1,0)--(.1,0);
\draw (-.1,1/2)--(.1,1/2);
\draw (-.1,3/2)--(.1,3/2);
\draw (-.1,1)--(.1,1);
\draw (-.1,2)--(.1,2);
\draw (-.1,5/2)--(.1,5/2);
%\node[left] at (0,2) {1/3};
%\node[left] at (0,5/12) {1/6};
%\node[left] at (0,0) {1/12};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{array}\right\}MM$
\caption{Simplicial approximation to $f : |K^2|\ra |L|$}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

I'm not able to draw the node at the required point. How can I draw this figure using `tikzpicture`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why `array` and why two `tikzpicture`s? (That leaves me confused whether `MM` is in math mode or not). It can be done like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[thick] (0,0) --  (0,9);    %% the line
   \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9}{
     \draw (-.1,\y) -- (.1,\y);
     }                              %% the horizontal segments
   \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt},xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0pt]
      (0,9) -- (0,7) node [midway,right,xshift=.1cm] {$MM$};    %% brace a top
   \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt},xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0pt]
      (0,7) -- (0,0) node [midway,right,xshift=.1cm] {$MM$};    %% brace at the bottom
   \foreach \y/\a in {9/1,8/{1/2},7/0}{
      \node[align=right] at (-.5,\y) {\a};
   }                                        %% top nodes
   \foreach \y/\a in {6/{1/3},2.91/{1/6},0/{1/12}}{
      \node[align=right] at (-.5,\y) {\a};
   }                                        %% bottom nodes
    %% The last two \foreach can be merged in to one. I left it as such
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It shows an error: "`stanalone.cls' not found.\usetikzlibrary" when I compile it with "kile1.2 beta 4" in ubuntu 10.04. How can I fix this?

Comment: @SoumitraSen: Replace `\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}` by `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz}`